# Stop form button from submit

Tags: jquery, forms, drupal-7, submit

I am attempting to stop a drupal form from submitting if two fields don't equate. I have two fields, enter your email and confirm email that both need to match prior to allowing the form to submit. the following code is inside of a $(document).read(function() call. How do I do this?

```
  $('#webform-client-form-27 #edit-submitted-confirm-email-address').blur(function() {

  if ($('#edit-submitted-email-address').val() == $('#edit-submitted-confirm-email-address').val() ) {
    $('#edit-submitted-email-address').css('border', '1px solid' );
    $('#edit-submitted-email-address').css('border-color', '#848484 #c1c1c1 #e1e1e1' );
    $('#edit-submitted-confirm-email-address').css('border', '1px solid' );
    $('#edit-submitted-confirm-email-address').css('border-color', '#848484 #c1c1c1 #e1e1e1' );

  }
  else {
    $('#edit-submitted-email-address').css('border', '2px solid red');
    $('#edit-submitted-confirm-email-address').css('border', '2px solid red');
  }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

it's actually quite simple :

```
$('#myForm').on('submit', function(){
    if ($('#theAddress').val() != $('#theConfirmation').val()) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

or if you have just those to check, you can compact it :

```
$('#myForm').on('submit', function(){
    return $('#theAddress').val() == $('#theConfirmation').val();
});
```

To explain you in details, the return value is used when you add handlers. If you return `true` javascript will proceed and submit the form on the `submit` event. If you return `false` it will simply stop.

Comment: The problem with doing it this way, is that it doesn't let drupal check the remaining values and run it's regular checks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form onsubmit="return validateInfoFunction()">
<input type="text" id="email1"/>
<input type="text" id="email2"/>
<input type="submit"/>
 </form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateInfoFunction(){

  if(document.getElementById("email1").value == document.getElementById("email2").value)
  {
   return true;
  }
else return false;
}
</script>
```

Returning false in an onsubmit event will stop the form submitting. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this directly using your form_name_validate function by matching the $form_state values of both textboxes and if value doesnt match you can throw form_set_error function.